Convert a list of strings to conversion functions
Currently I can create a list of conversion functions like the following:
casts = [float, float, int, str, int, str, str]

but I would like to do it in the following manner:
casts = input("Enter the casts: ") # this would be str str int int float

I tried just doing cast.split()
but that only outputs a list of strings and not the conversion functions.
How would I go about achieving my objective?

What is the actual use case? This appears to be an XY problem.

When I open a file that has rows and columns I use the types to cast the columns so that I do not need to manually convert the columns

use a lookup dict, with values like "float": float

A function is not a name. The blessed way is to use a dictionary to map names to functions:
casts={'int': int, 'float': float, 'str': str}
cast = casts[input('Enter the cast name')]

An anti-pattern allows to search for names in a module:
import builtins
cast = getattr(builtins, input('Enter the cast name)]

But beware, although it is allowed by the language, this breaks the separation between the user code and the internals of the language. You should avoid it if you can...

From your comments, what you are looking for is something close to:
cast_ref = {'int': int, 'float': float, 'str': str}
casts = [cast_ref[src] for src in input('Enter the casts: ').split()]


Sometimes the files that I use this for have different amounts of columns so rather than hard code the columns I want to be able to create the conversions as needed

This method does not appear to allow me to enter more than one key instead of a list of keys

@capnhud In that case, please edit your question to clarify how you want to be able to input keys.

@capnhud there is more than enough information here to hep you handle that case, come one now

@juanpa.arrivillaga I must be missing it then because all I get is KeyErrors

@capnhud You have two questions here: "How can I convert "int" into int()" and "how can I split up a string by spaces"? The first is the heart of the post, and this answer addresses it well. The second is answered by this post. Combining the two should be enough.

If you don't know the data types ahead of time, you can use pandas' built-in data type inference mechanisms to automatically detect the data types of each column.
import pandas as pd

# Read the data file into a pandas DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

# Infer data types for each column
df = df.infer_objects()

# Print the resulting DataFrame
print(df)



casts = [float, float, int, str, int, str, str]

def tonumtype(item,num)
tonumb = f"""
{item}({num}) """
return eval(tonumb)

tonumtype(casts[1],10) = float(10)


eval should really be avoided when possible. Also, this will raise a SyntaxError.
